# Graph API and PHP SDK returns different results

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of members of our school group. The problem is, if I try it using Graph API explorer, results are ok (to be specific, one of the member's id: `732260790195849`)

When I try it using my PHP code, ID differs a little `732293256859269`

My PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<?php
require('fbsdk/autoload.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
...

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('...', '...');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( '...' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
}

if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/mygroupid/members?limit=2000' );
  $response = $request->execute();

    $data = $response->getGraphObject();
    echo '<pre>', var_dump($data), '</pre>';

} else {
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am logged as a member of that group.. 
Any ideas why is this happening ? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're retrieving an app-scoped ID within an application and probably the real (or another scoped) ID with the Graph Explorer.  This is to protect user information.  In any event, the ID you retrieve will link to the correct person.  I'll also add that this ID will never change within the app.

Comment: Uhm, when I try to request /732293256859269 I get Unsupported get request.. The real ID (from Graph API Explorer) is working fine

Comment: The two IDs can not be used interchangeably within the same setting.  One will only work with the Graph Explorer and one within your app.