# Retrive Facebook username or user-id with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way I can retrive users id? I know how get id from getGraphObjec but that id is not the id I want. I found something like http://graph.facebook.com/userid. I want that id, for example I generate "10205575645933169" from getGraphObject, but I want "1313375997" which is used in http://graph.facebook.com/1313375997. I don't even know if that is possible, but if it is, does anyone know a way to do it? Thank you

```html
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('856997051006897','8e034c9c2bb159f9eba8f251dcc68eba');
$facebook = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/FacebookLogin/index.php');

try {
 if($session = $facebook->getSessionFromRedirect()){
  $_SESSION['facebook'] = $session->getToken();
  
  header('Location: index.php');
 }
 
 if(isset($_SESSION['facebook'])) {
  $session = new Facebook\FacebookSession($_SESSION['facebook']);
  $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
  $request = $request->execute();
  
  $user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();  
  } 
} catch(Facebook\FacebookRequestException $e) {
 // Facebook error
} catch(Exception $e) {
 // local error
}
```

And I call it with $user['id']; in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.0 it´s not possible to retrieve the "username" or the "real/global ID" anymore. You will only get the real name of the user and an App Scoped ID. With the username, you could get the "real" ID of a user, so the whole concept with the App Scoped IDs would be void if it would still be possible to get the username or the real/global ID.

Check out the changelog for more information about recent changes: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0):

Graph API returns APP SCOPED USER ID. You can work with that ID in your code. It's still the same user.
You can do requests like

```
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/'.$app_scoped_user_id);
```

I used to have the same problem. You can check it here [Graph API and PHP SDK returns different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548145/graph-api-and-php-sdk-returns-different-results)

Comment: I know I can use it, but I want to retrive facebooks username, ie www.facebook.com/zmuci <- I want this word zmuci which I cant take ith app id. :) Or at least I dont know how.

Comment: If you want to just link the profile page, you can use this format: https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/<APPSCOPEDID> and you will be redirected to the original profile page. I am not sure if you can get the original link.